# Down-sampling an image before processing, does not speed-up processing in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

In OpenCV, I got the bright idea of capturing video from a camera at 720p, but down-sampling to 480p before processing. That way I get faster processing but keep HD output images.

```
[1] cap.read(hd)          <-- 80ms
[2] Imgproce.resize(hd,sd)
[3] BackgroundSubtractorMOG.apply(sd)   <-- 20ms

^ takes 100ms
```

Here's the weird thing. This chain takes the same amount of time whether I downsample or not. If I remove the downsample, I get:

```
[1] cap.read(hd)   <--- 20ms
[2] BackgroundSubtractorMOG.apply(hd)  <-- 80ms

^ also takes 100ms
```

I'm befuddled. Why would the read time depend on what I do later on!?

**EDIT: As requested, some real code:**

```
BackgroundSubtractorMOG mog = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG();
Mat captured = new Mat();
Mat foreground = new Mat();
Mat downsampled = new Mat();

while (true) {
    long MEASURE_all = System.nanoTime();    
    vc.read(captured);          
    long MEASURE_resize = System.nanoTime();

    Imgproc.resize(captured, downsampled, 
       new org.opencv.core.Size(processing_width, processing_height)); 
    long MEASURE_foreground = System.nanoTime();

    mog.apply(downsampled, foreground, -1); 
    long MEASURE_draw = System.nanoTime();

    // some more stuff

    System.out.println("retrieve: " + ((MEASURE_resize) - MEASURE_all)/1000000 + 
                 ", resize: " + ((MEASURE_foreground) - MEASURE_resize)/1000000 // ...
 }
```

Comment: Is that pseudocode? If so, please post the original. Also, how did you profile this?

Comment: edited. only thing I can come up with is that this webcam needs 100ms to prepare a frame, so if the loop is too fast read() takes longer. but the webcam can do 30fps so that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Actually, that's it. If I remove the processing (savings of 20ms) then vc.retrieve() starts taking up the entire 100ms ! Guess I'll delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was gonna close it, but it may be of help to someone in theory so the answer is...

... the camera/driver seems to struggle to deliver a frame faster than one every 100ms, so the savings in processing time can't be seen.

read() becomes the bottleneck.